# Low-Rank Approximations Book

Tags: reference-request, numerical-linear-algebra

I am looking for a source (book, online book, etc..) where I can find the theory behind low-rank approximations of matrices. In particular, I am interested in low-rank approximations used in optimization problems, such as minimizations of the Euclidean and Forbenius norms.

I have some background in basic and numberical linear algebra, but I am looking for a source that is simple and straightforward.

Sincerly, 
Amit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The book [Low Rank Approximation: Algorithms, Implementation, Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1447122267) by Ivan Markovsky might be of intrest here. The table of content is available in the Amazon link.